# Связать PHP и запуск действия через JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте.

Пожалуйста подскажите с какой стороны подступить к решению такой задачи:

Есть конструкция в HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="4">
```

Есть массивы в PHP (их конечно можно переименовать):

```
<? 
 $id_1 = array(1,2,3);
 $id_2 = array(5,6,7);
 $id_3 = array(8,9,10);
 $id_4 = array(11,12,13);
?>
```

с помощью следующего JS кода при включении двух любых checkbox запускается определеное действие:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
var checked = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
if (checked == 2) {
 ---действие---;
}
});
```

Как сделать так, чтобы действием стал запуск отдельного кода PHP в котором бы использовались массивы, соответсвующие именам checkbox?

P.s. Поясню для чего все делается. Есть таблица с перечнем банков и условиями их кредитования. Кроме того, созданы массивы в которых записаны переплаты по месяцам по каждому банку (т.е. [0] - переплата по кредиту в первый месяц по данному банку, [1] - во второй и так далее. Хочу сделать так, чтобы по выбору двух банков через checkbox появлялось окно, в котором через google chart построится график с переплатами обоих банков. Как-то так...

Comment: Используя ajax можете вызывать отдельные скрипты на php.

Опишите полную цель задачи, сейчас не особо понятно, для чего все делается.

Comment: @Vasily Koshelev пояснил.

Comment: Думаю, что было бы проще делать запрос на ajax к скрипту, передавая id выбранных банков.
В php скрипте вытаскивать из бд данные, забивать их в массив и преобразовывать в json.
Принимать ответ в понятном для js json-e и обновлять график в соответствии с этими данными.

Comment: Спасибо @Vasily Koshelev. Но вытягивать данные из БД значит тянуть еще кучу всего и с фронта, а массивы уже созданы и готовы, даже в целях экономии времени хочу найти способ уже с созданными массивами. Понял одно, что без json не обойтись.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
  var checked = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
  if (checked.length == 2) {
    var names = $.map(checked, function(ch){
      return $(ch).attr('name');
    });
    
    // Далее выполняем ajax запрос к php скрипту, куда и передаём names
    $.ajax({
      url : 'https://httpbin.org/post',
      method : 'post',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      // data : {names: names}, автоматически выполнится $.param, будет names[]=3&names[]=4
      data : JSON.stringify({names: names}),
      dataType: 'json',
      success : function(res){
        var form = JSON.parse(res.data);
        console.log(form.names);
      }
    });

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="checkbox" name="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="4">
```

В php вы получите массив `['names']` вида `[1, 3]` в json теле запроса:

```
<?php
// Обратите внимание, данные не в форме `$_POST`, а в теле запроса, их нужно распарсить вручную.
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
$names = $input['names'];
// Имитируем ответ от httpbin.org, чтобы не менять js
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode(['data' => json_encode(['names' => $names])]);
exit();
```

---

Чтобы получить данные в массив `$_POST` нужно отправлять `x-www-formurlencoded` запрос:

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
  var checked = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
  if (checked.length == 2) {
    var names = $.map(checked, function(ch){
      return $(ch).attr('name');
    });
    
    // Далее выполняем ajax запрос к php скрипту, куда и передаём names
    $.ajax({
      url : 'https://httpbin.org/post',
      method : 'post',
      data : {names: names},
      // data : $.param({names: names}), // это выполнится автоматически
      success : function(res){
        console.log(res.form['names[]']);
      }
    });

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="checkbox" name="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="4">
```

PHP в этом случае:

```
<?php
$names = $_POST['names'];
// Имитируем ответ от httpbin.org, чтобы не менять js
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode(['form' => ['names[]' => $names]]);
exit();
```

Comment: ваш ответ кажется самым логичным, но почему-то не работает у меня. Я правильно, понимаю, что вместо https://httpbin.org/post добавляю путь к php файлу в котором через $_POST['names'] по логике должен получать массив? и появлятся этот массив должен без перезагрузке этого файла?

Comment: @Oktu, добавил как бы выглядел скрипт php, чтобы всё работало также, как `httpbin.org`. Дело в том, что php не парсит json тело запроса самостоятельно.

Comment: Во-первых, спасибо что помогаете! Второе, поэтапно разбираюсь в вопросе: я решил упросить, и убрал строку dataType: 'json', и после этого массив стал доступен просто через $name = $_POST['names']; Можно пойти таким путем?

Comment: @Oktu, `dataType` не мог на это повлиять. Он отвечает за ожидаемый формат ответа от сервера. Либо вы изменили что-то другое, либо изначально всё работало и вы неправильно проверяли.

Answer (score 1):

Во время генерации страницы передавайте массивы связанным инпутам в атрибуты **data** и потом тяните их через **js** по условию.

В php файле массивы объединяйте в строки, эти строки присваивайте атрибутам **data**

```
somewhere in your.php
...
$id1 = implode(',' , array(1,2,3));
...
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="1" data-array="<?=$id1;?>" />
...
```

```js
var checkTocheck = function(){
    var checked = $("input:checked").attr('name');
    var url, data;
    switch(checked){
            case '1':
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
                url = "4.php"
            break;
    }
    data = $("input:checked").data('array').split(',');
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            $('body').append(data);
        }
    })
};

checkTocheck();

$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click",checkTocheck);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="1" data-array="1,2,3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="2" data-array="5,6,7" />
<input type="checkbox" name="3" data-array="8,9,10" />
<input type="checkbox" name="4" data-array="11,12,13" />
<div id="console"></div>
```

Comment: А где здесь передача данных в PHP??

Comment: На самом деле неясно, зачем брать данные массивов с фронта (которые туд попадают с бэка), чтобы вернуть их назад на бэк. Достаточно отправлять только `name` и по нему привязывать массивы с данными на бэке.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте ajax. С использованием jQuery.ajax это будет выглядеть, примерно, так:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "../your_file.php",
    data: $('#form').serialize(), // Сериализация формы
    complete: function(data) {
        // Получаем ответ сервера
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        // Если при обработке запроса возникла ошибка
    }
});
```

В PHP получаете данные и обрабатываете их в соответствии с Вашими требованиями.

Документация [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

Можно так http://codepen.io/keesik/pen/xqLorw

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
  var checked = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
  if (checked.length > 1) {
    var data = [];
    checked.each(function(){
        data.push($(this).attr('name'))
    });
    $.ajax({
      url : '/Путь к скрипту на сервере',
      method : 'get', // или post
      data : 'checked=' + data.join(','), // данные в php скрипте будут достпны в переменной $_REQUEST['checked']. Все выбранные пункты будут перечислены через запятую. 
      success : function(res){
        console.log(res); // ответ от сервера
        alert('Ajax request done');
      }
    })
  }
});
```